# Replacing $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{R}$ in group presentation constructions

Tags: group-theory

Consider a finitely generated group $G$.  Assume for a moment it is genearated by $n = 2$ elements.  Then the group $G$ has a presentation as a some quotient $\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z} / H$.  Now $\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z} / H$ naturally embeds into $\mathbb{R} \ast \mathbb{R} / H$.  The latter may be thought of as the usual finite group presentation construction extended to allow for the application of real (possibly non-integral) exponents to the generating elements.  If we write $\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z} = F\{a,b\}$ then one element of $\mathbb{R} \ast \mathbb{R} / H$ might be $a^{-1/2}b^{\pi-1}$, for example.  We can carry out a similar construction for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

This construction associates (after choice of presentation) a finitely generated group $G$ with a 'continuous' topological group $X$ containing $G$.

It is tempting to think of $X$ as a continuous version of $G$, but this may be deceptive.

Is it?  Also, does this construction have a name?

Comment: I don't think this is the "right" definition, because you should want to somehow interpolate the relations over $\mathbb{R}$.  For instance, when you apply your construction to the presentation $\langle a,b|aba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle$, you get a highly nonabelian group, because non-integer powers of $a$ and $b$ have no reason to commute with each other.   You seem to be trying to define a nonabelian analogue of the operation $G\mapsto G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}$, but the abelian version of your definition would only tensor the generators with $\mathbb{R}$, not the relations.

Comment: Your construction also gives different results for different presentations of the same group.  For instance, $\langle a|\rangle$ vs $\langle a,b|ab^{-1}\rangle$ are both presentations of $\mathbb{Z}$, but your construction turns the first into $\mathbb{R}$ and the second into some horrible nonabelian mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my comments I indicated that you have the "wrong" definition.  In fact, in a certain sense there is no "right" definition.

Let's try to axiomatize the construction you are trying to define.  One reasonable axiomatization is the following.  You are asking for a functor $R$ from groups to groups such that $R(\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{R}$ and $R$ preserves colimits.  (If you replace "groups" by "abelian groups", this characterizes the functor $G\mapsto G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}$ up to canonical natural isomorphism.)

However, I claim that no such functor $R$ exists.  Indeed, suppose it did.  Then we must have $R(\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{R}*\mathbb{R}$.  Consider the homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ which sends $1$ to $ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are the generators of $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$.  Then $R(f)$ must be some homomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}*\mathbb{R}$.  Furthermore, $f$ has the property that $(Id,0)\circ f=(0,Id)\circ f=Id$, where $(g,h)$ denotes the map $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ induced by a pair of maps $g,h:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$.  Since $R$ preserves colimits, the the same must be true of $R(f)$.  In particular, this means $R(f)(1)$ is some word $a^{r_1}b^{s_1}\dots a^{r_n}b^{s_n}\in\mathbb{R}*\mathbb{R}$ (for $r_i,s_i\in \mathbb{R}$) such that $\sum r_i=\sum s_i=1$.  But it is easy to see that there is no such word that has a square root in $\mathbb{R}*\mathbb{R}$.  Thus there is no possible value for $R(f)(1/2)$, which is a contradiction.

On the other hand, here is a different axiomatization for which your desired construction does exist.  Define an $\mathbb{R}$-group to be a group $G$ together with a binary operation $\mathbb{R}\times G\to G$, written $(r,g)\mapsto g^r$, such that $g^1=g$, $g^0=1$, $g^{r+s}=g^rg^s$, and $(g^r)^s=g^{rs}$.  There is then a forgetful functor from the category of groups to the category of $\mathbb{R}$-groups, and by general universal algebra nonsense it has a left adjoint $R$.  Roughly speaking, $R(G)$ is defined by taking a group and formally adjoining to it new operations $g\mapsto g^r$ satisfying the axioms of an $\mathbb{R}$-group.  (If you apply these definitions to abelian groups, with the additional assumption that $(gh)^r=g^rh^r$, then an $\mathbb{R}$-abelian group is just an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, and the functor $R$ is $G\mapsto G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}$.)

However, this construction still look quite different from the definition you suggest.  For instance, while $R(\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{R}$, it is not true that $R(\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{R}*\mathbb{R}$.  The reason is essentially the same as the reason that the first axiomatization failed: in $\mathbb{R}*\mathbb{R}$, there is no way to define elements like $(ab)^r$ when $r$ is not an integer.  So $R(\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z})$ is actually much larger than $\mathbb{R}*\mathbb{R}$: it contains lots of new elements like $(ab)^r$ or $((ab)^rab^s)^t$.

Also, I am not even sure that this is the "right" definition of $\mathbb{R}$-group.  For instance, some additional axioms that might make sense to assume are $(hgh^{-1})^r=hg^rh^{-1}$ and $(gh)^r=g^rh^r$ if $g$ and $h$ commute, and there might be additional desirable axioms I haven't thought of.  I'm sure that people have thought about this definition before (as a non-abelian version of modules over a ring), but I wasn't able to find anything useful by googling.